# How to disable Anchor(a ) tag on pageload or (by default disable) and enable it using jquery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to disable Anchor(a ) tag on pageload or (by default disable) and enable it using jquery or Javascript??

Answer (score 2):

You can change `href` attribute to `data-href` and add `href` attribute using:

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-href]').each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        self.attr('href', self.data('href'));
    });
});
```

this will iterate over all elements that have data-href and add href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to disable the anchor tags by default, you can add a class to each tag and remove the calss using javascript.

```
.not-active {
    pointer-events: none; // disables all the clicks
    cursor: default; // shows the default cursor when you hover it instead of hand
}
```

Also you can change the font color and others so that the text does not appear like a link.

[EDIT]

```
<script>
    var anchorElements=document.getElementsByTagName("a"); //Gives the list of all anchor tag elements in the page as an array.
    for(i=0;i<anchorElements.length;i++) // Iterate over the array
        anchorElements[i].classList.remove("not-active"); // for each element .classList returns the list of classes specified. remove() is an array function to remove an element in the array
</script>
```

If you are using jQuery you can use removeClass() jQuery function

```
$("a").removeClass("not-active");
```

Comment: How can I Remove calss using javascript ?? plz help

Comment: but  I want to remove the class  permanently. Here After performing javascript it removed but after page loading againg its become deactivate. So can remove the class permanently.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your comment ("How can I Remove calss using javascript ?? plz help") on removing class, there is a property called classList that contains its class attributes. This property provides methods that make it easy to add or remove a class. Something like:

```
var myItemClasses= document.getElementById("item").classList;
myItemClasses.remove("my-classname"); // to remove
myItemClasses.add("my-classname"); // to add
```

Hope this helps.